# Font-Awesome Tiktok icon (fab fa-tiktok) appearing as books

Tags: html, css, icons, font-awesome

I am using Font Awesome 5 (brands). The tiktok Icon is displayed as a stack of books instead of the stylized T.
Attempted using the local directory of Font-Awesome as well as linking the style with the url.
My other site is displaying the icon properly, using the same stylesheets and font-awesome version.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.3/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-iBBXm8fW90+nuLcSKlbmrPcLa0OT92xO1BIsZ+ywDWZCvqsWgccV3gFoRBv0z+8dLJgyAHIhR35VZc2oM/gI1w==" crossorigin="anonymous" />

<a style="font-size: 3vh" class="social-button sb-facebook shape-none sb-light-skin"><i class="fab fa-facebook"></i></a>
<a style="font-size: 3vh" class="social-button sb-instagram shape-none sb-light-skin"><i class="fab fa-instagram"></i></a>
<a style="font-size: 3vh" class="social-button sb-tiktok shape-none sb-light-skin"><i class="fab fa-tiktok"></i></a>
```

[error icon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GONXZ.png)

[expected icons](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ysyQP.png)

class pulls font-awesome.

Any advise would be much appreciated

Comment: Can you provide an image of what you are getting and what you are expecting?

Comment: the links to error icon and expected icons are the values that I get and what I expect, respectively

Comment: I copied your code and opened the html file in my Chrome browser. And it is showing exactly what you are expecting.